# How to save form data more than once?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am making a recurring app. I need to be able to save the form data more than once. If I try to do this it does not work:

```
for a in range(1, 10):
    foo.save()
```

Comment: do you want to save and create a new object every time you save ?

Comment: you need to save different objects with different primary keys, or it won't work at all

Comment: @karthikr The data comes from a submitted form to my views file. I want to add the form data n number of times. If that's what you mean?

Comment: n number of times to the same model object ?

Comment: @karthikr  I meant n can be any number. Like I want to save the data 5 times, or 100 times or n number of times..

Comment: @yeshwanthnadella you probably have a model associated to that form. Each time you save a form, a new entity is created (or updated). You want the same form to spawn different entities in your DB, you need a different logic to save them, that's not enough

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I am trying make a recurring calendar. So based on the start date and end date I should be able to save the form data n number of times. Could you explain a little more what I need to do here?

Comment: @karthikr yes to same model object.

Comment: check my answer for explanations

Answer (score 4):

better in an answer than in a comment:

```
# foo is your (valid) form
# bar is your object's instance
bar = foo.save(commit=False)

for a in range(1, 10):
    bar.save() # save the object
    bar.pk = None # reset the pk, next iteration of the loop will save a new one
```

source: [Docs Almighty (1.4)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances)

Comment: thanks for help. I figured it out. I just did in a different way. I added the loop to when I was creating the objects. Appreciate your time!